# Correct function notation (domain/range) for $f(x)=\sqrt{x+5}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, elementary-set-theory, notation

I have $f(x)=\sqrt{x+5}$ and I want to write this in a proper function notation. I tried the notations
$$
f:\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R, \quad f(x)=\sqrt{x+5} 
\tag 1
$$
and
$$
f:\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R, \quad 
x\mapsto \sqrt{x+5}
\tag 2
$$
But my problem: Isn't it wrong to denote the domain with $\mathbb R$, because we have the condition $x\geq -5$? If so, what is the correct notation?

Thanks!

Comment: As the domain is the interval $\left[-5,+\infty\right[$, you can write: $$f:\left[-5,+\infty\right[\to\mathbb{R},\quad x\mapsto\sqrt{x+5}$$

Comment: @Angelo the range isnt $\mathcal{R}$

Comment: Range is an ambiguous term. The codomain is R. The image of the domain is the set of non-negative reals. The term range can refer to either.

Comment: In $f:A\to B$, $A$ is domain and B is codomain. That is to say, $f$ must be defined on $A$ (on all points of $A$) and range, that is the set $\{f(x) :x\in A\} \subseteq B$

Answer (score 2):

As the domain is the interval $\left[-5,+\infty\right[$, we can write: $$f:\left[-5,+\infty\right[\to\mathbb{R},\quad x\mapsto\sqrt{x+5}\;.$$

Even though the range of the function is $\left[0,+\infty\right[$, we can write, instead of the range, the codomain $\mathbb{R}$ after the arrow anyway.

Comment: You should explain the difference between the range and the codomain.

Comment: The range of a function $f:A\to B$ is the set $f(A)=\left\{f(x): x\in A\right\}$ and it is a proper or improper subset of $B$ that is $f(A)\subseteq B$.

Comment: I meant that you should explain you were using $\mathbb{R}$ to denote the codomain rather than the range.

Comment: It does not need any explanation, it is obvious that $\mathbb{R}$ is not the range of the function but is the codomain.

Answer (score 0):

$f$ is defined for all real number greater than or equal to $-5$ so your domain is $[-5,\infty)$. Further, the range is the set of all non-negative real numbers. So the range is $[0,\infty)$.